# Unreadable verify code from Microsoft; outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com

I want to change my `outlook.com` account's privacy setting, So I have to verify with Text Message from Microsoft.
But when I receive SMS from microsoft I get something as follows

```
〶㈷〶㌳〶㉡〶㐱〶㈷〶㉦〶㐷〰㈰〶㈷〶㌲〰㈰〰㌲〰㌹〰㌶〰㌴〰㌶〰㌰〰㌸〰㈰〶㈸〶㐷〰㈰〶㌹〶㐶〶㐸〶㈷〶㐶〰㈰〶愹〶㉦〰㈰〶㈷〶㐵〶㐶〶捣〶㉡〶捣〰㈰〶㉤〶㌳〶㈷〶㈸〰㈰〰㑤〰㘹〰㘳〰㜲〰㙦〰㜳〰㙦〰㘶〰㜴
```

What's wrong?
 
How can I receive SMS in English characters?

Comment: Does this happen every time you try to verify by SMS?

Comment: @MichaelFrank, Almost yes, but rarely no

Comment: It sure looks like the message doesn’t have the right encoding. I have no idea why is happening, but if I’d have to guess, I’d say that it could have to do with your language settings inside Outlook (loooong shot though).

Comment: Not that it's very helpful, but you may also want to [follow this](https://forums.yahoo.net/t5/Password-and-sign-in/In-Danger-of-Hacking/td-p/480961). It seems similar, but no answer.